# With Acrobat Javascript can you open a file in the recent documents list?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, adobe, registry, acrobat

I have a round-about way I am planning on launching acrobat from SharePoint so I can manipulate the file both on the way in and the way out, but I am curious if there is a way to launch Adobe Acrobat 9 Standard edition and have it automatically open document 1 from the recent documents list.

I know its possible to open a new document at app launch with code such as:

```
TrustedRoutine = app.trustedFunction( function(){
    app.beginPriv();
    if (app.activeDocs.length<1){
    app.openDoc("/C/Documents and Settings/USERNAME/Desktop/FILENAME.pdf");
    }
    app.endPriv();
})
```

What I am curious about doing though is to put an object or parameter into the openDoc that will cause it to read that key from the registry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: Been researching more, and I realize that VBScript can do additional things. Would VBScript be able to do it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a ton of research, we have come to realize this is not possible to completely rewrite the integration without writing out own OCX control to handle the OpenDocument call from sharepoint.  Because of this, the company is going to instead invest in upgrading to Acrobat X which already has this control written.